# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have created a normal Spring project1, which is calling a method present in other project2(Spting Boot). ThisProject2 contains RestTemplate object and endpoints. I am getting NoclassdefFoundError. I have added below maven dependecy.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

After the adding dependency, Maven Build is successful but getting error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate
```

Below code from Project 1 :

```
package com.citi.gfs.data.genesis.cons.writeback.solution;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.mail.Session;

import scala.reflect.ClassTag;
import org.apache.commons.lang.exception.ExceptionUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.citi.gfs.data.genesis.cons.writeback.constants.WritebackAppConstants;
import com.citi.gfs.data.genesis.cons.writeback.dto.AuditCompleteDto;
import com.citi.gfs.data.genesis.cons.writeback.dto.AuditInitiateDto;
import com.citi.gfs.data.genesis.cons.writeback.helper.SparkSessConn;
import com.citi.gfs.data.genesis.cons.writeback.util.CommonUtil;
import com.citi.gfs.data.genesis.cons.writeback.util.CustomLogger;
import com.citi.gfs.data.genesis.cons.audit.lib.services.AuditLibService;
import com.citi.gfs.data.genesis.cons.common.dto.AuditResponse;

//@ComponentScan("com.citi.gfs.data.genesis.cons")
public class WriteBackSolution{

    static CommonUtil cmUtil = new CommonUtil();
    static WriteBackSolution wbc = new WriteBackSolution();
    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(WriteBackSolution.class);
    static AuditCompleteDto completeAudit= new AuditCompleteDto();
    static AuditInitiateDto initiateAudit= new AuditInitiateDto();
    
    

    public static void logging(String msg, String loglevel, String timeflag) {

        CustomLogger.logging(log, msg, loglevel, timeflag);
    }

    public static void logging(String msg, String loglevel) {

        CustomLogger.logging(log, msg, loglevel);
    }

    public static void logging(String msg) {

        CustomLogger.logging(log, msg);
    }
    

    
    public void writeBack(SparkSession spark, String batchId, Broadcast<Map<String, String>> br, String fileName,
            String logPath, Map<String, String> oracleDbDetails,String hiveTblName)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException, SQLException {

        String tblhdfsPath = br.value().get(WritebackAppConstants.TBLHDFSPATH);
        String oracleStatusTblname = br.value().get(WritebackAppConstants.ORACLESTATUSTABLENAME);
        String oracleStatusTblSchema = br.value().get(WritebackAppConstants.ORACLESTATUSTABLESCHEMA);
        String filePath = br.value().get(WritebackAppConstants.PROCESSINGDIR) + WritebackAppConstants.SLASH + fileName;
        String smtpHostServerKey = WritebackAppConstants.SMTPHOSTSERVERKEY;
        String smtpHostServerValue = WritebackAppConstants.SMTPHOSTSERVERVALUE;
        String executionDate = cmUtil.getCurrDateTime(br.value().get(WritebackAppConstants.EXECUTIONDATEFORMAT));
        String environment = br.value().get(WritebackAppConstants.ENV);
        String hiveSchema = br.value().get(WritebackAppConstants.HIVESCHEMA);
        String createTblFormat = br.value().get(WritebackAppConstants.TBLFORMAT);
        Session session = cmUtil.getEmailSession(smtpHostServerKey, smtpHostServerValue);
        String tblName = "";
        String query = "";
        String oracleValues = "";
        String status = WritebackAppConstants.RUNNING;
        String fileType = "";
        Dataset<Row> inputDf = null;
        int dfRecordCount = 0;
        int traierRecordCount = 0;

        logging("Validating file--" + filePath, "INFO", "Y");

        Map<String, String> emailMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put(WritebackAppConstants.TBLHDFSPATH, tblhdfsPath);
        config.put(WritebackAppConstants.ENV, environment);
        config.put(WritebackAppConstants.CREATEFORMAT, createTblFormat);
        config.put(WritebackAppConstants.HIVESCHEMA, hiveSchema);
        config.put(WritebackAppConstants.HIVETARGETTBL, hiveTblName);

        String startTime = cmUtil.getCurrDateTime(br.value().get(WritebackAppConstants.STARTANDENDTIMEFORMAT));

        emailMap.put(WritebackAppConstants.STARTTIME, startTime);
        emailMap.put(WritebackAppConstants.HIVETARGETTBL, hiveTblName);
        // fetching table name from file
        tblName = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf(WritebackAppConstants.SLASH) + 1, filePath.lastIndexOf(
                WritebackAppConstants.UNDERSCORE, filePath.lastIndexOf(WritebackAppConstants.UNDERSCORE) - 1));
        fileType = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf(WritebackAppConstants.FULLSTOP) + 1, filePath.length());
 
        oracleValues = " '" + batchId + "'" + "," + "'" + fileName + "'" + "," + "'" + tblName + "'" + "," + null + ","
                + "'" + status + "'" + "," + "'" + startTime + "'" + "," + null + "," + null;

        query = "Insert into " + oracleStatusTblname + "(" + oracleStatusTblSchema + ") " + "values" + "("
                + oracleValues + ")";

        logging("Insert into Oracle table--" + query);
        try {
            cmUtil.oracleDataEntry(oracleDbDetails, query);
        } catch (Exception ex) {

            logging("insert into oracle table " + ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(ex));
        }

        inputDf = cmUtil.readDf(spark, filePath, fileType);
        dfRecordCount = cmUtil.sourceDfCount(inputDf);

        // Record count validation

        traierRecordCount = cmUtil.getTrailerDfCount(inputDf, fileType, dfRecordCount);

        emailMap.put(WritebackAppConstants.RECORDCOUNT, Integer.toString(dfRecordCount));
        emailMap.put(WritebackAppConstants.TBLNAME, tblName);
        emailMap.put(WritebackAppConstants.BATCHID, batchId);
        emailMap.put(WritebackAppConstants.FILENAME, fileName);

        logging("Count validation--Df count" + dfRecordCount, "INFO", "Y");
        logging("Count validation--trailer count" + traierRecordCount, "INFO", "Y");

        boolean valFlag = cmUtil.countValidation(dfRecordCount, traierRecordCount);

        cmUtil.loadDataInConfig(config, tblName, fileType, filePath, fileName, oracleStatusTblname);
        cmUtil.loadSessionDetailsInConfig(config, executionDate, logPath, batchId);
        if (valFlag) {
            cmUtil.writebackValid(inputDf, spark, config, br, oracleDbDetails, emailMap, session);
        }

        else {
            cmUtil.writebackInValid(config, br, oracleDbDetails, emailMap, session);

        }

    }
    
    //@Bean public RestTemplate restTemplate() { return new RestTemplate(); }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        log.info("inside main..");
        String envconfigfile = "";
        String batchId = "";
        String fileName = "";
        String logPath = "";
        String appconfig = "";
        SparkSession spark = null;
        
        ///////////
        
        CustomLogger.initlogger(WritebackAppConstants.LOGFILENAME,
                "/data/1/gfbcbn/bin/apps/etl/gen_snapshot/jar"+"/");
        
        
         try {
                Class<?> processEnvironmentClass = Class.forName("java.lang.ProcessEnvironment");
                Field theEnvironmentField = processEnvironmentClass.getDeclaredField("theEnvironment");
                theEnvironmentField.setAccessible(true);
                Map<String, String> env = (Map<String, String>) theEnvironmentField.get(null);
                env.put("AUDIT_BASE_URL","http://**-****-****:8080");
                Field theCaseInsensitiveEnvironmentField = processEnvironmentClass.getDeclaredField("theCaseInsensitiveEnvironment");
                theCaseInsensitiveEnvironmentField.setAccessible(true);
                Map<String, String> cienv = (Map<String, String>)     theCaseInsensitiveEnvironmentField.get(null);
                cienv.put("AUDIT_BASE_URL","http://**-****-****:8080");
              } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                Class[] classes = Collections.class.getDeclaredClasses();
                Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
                for(Class cl : classes) {
                  if("java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap".equals(cl.getName())) {
                    Field field = cl.getDeclaredField("m");
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    Object obj = field.get(env);
                    Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) obj;
                    map.clear();
                    map.put("AUDIT_BASE_URL","http://sd-e3ca-fd19:8080");
                  }
                }
              }
            
        initiateAudit.setClientID("Writeback");
        initiateAudit.setBatchID(batchId);
        initiateAudit.setSubscriptionID("1");
        initiateAudit.setFileName(fileName);
        
        System.out.println("Initiate audit");
        try {
            System.out.println("Creating audit obj");
            String env1=System.getenv("AUDIT_BASE_URL");
            System.out.println("AUDIT_BASE_URL=="+env1);
            AuditLibService auditLibService =new AuditLibService();
            
            log.debug(auditLibService);
            AuditResponse auditResponse1=null;
            System.out.println("Initiate audit req");
            auditResponse1=auditLibService.initiateAuditRequest("TEST",initiateAudit);
            log.debug(auditResponse1);
        System.out.println("response msg--"+auditResponse1.getRequestId()+"==="+auditResponse1.getRespMessage());
        
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        { 
            log.info("catch Audit-----");
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.debug("exception in initaitae audit-"+ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(e));
            }
        ///////////////////////////
        System.exit(1);
        if (args.length < 5) {
            log.info("Expected number of parameters 5. Number of parameters received: " + args.length);
            throw new IOException("Problem in passing arguments to Writeback process:" + args.length);

        }

        else {
            envconfigfile = args[0].trim();
            fileName = args[1].trim();
            batchId = args[2].trim();
            logPath = args[3].trim();
            appconfig = args[4].trim();

        }
        
        String tblName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf(WritebackAppConstants.UNDERSCORE,
                fileName.lastIndexOf(WritebackAppConstants.UNDERSCORE) - 1));
        String logDir=logPath.substring(0, logPath.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
        CustomLogger.initlogger(WritebackAppConstants.LOGFILENAME + tblName,
                logDir+"/");
        
        
        
        Map<String, String> oracleDbDetails = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        oracleDbDetails = cmUtil.configFileRead(envconfigfile, oracleDbDetails);
        oracleDbDetails = cmUtil.configFileRead(appconfig, oracleDbDetails);
        spark = SparkSessConn.getSparkSession("WritebackService_" + tblName,oracleDbDetails);
        //Map<String, String> configMap =cmUtil.oracleConfigData(oracleDbDetails, spark);
        //Dataset<Row> tblDf=cmUtil.getTblInfoFromOracle(spark, oracleDbDetails);
        
        Map<String, String> hiveTblMap =cmUtil.readLookupFile(oracleDbDetails.get(WritebackAppConstants.MAPCONFIG));
        ClassTag<Map<String, String>> brClass = scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(Map.class);
        Broadcast<Map<String, String>> br = spark.sparkContext().broadcast(oracleDbDetails, brClass);
        String hiveTblName=cmUtil.fetchHiveTableName(hiveTblMap,fileName,oracleDbDetails,br,batchId,logPath);
            
        initiateAudit.setClientID("Writeback");
        initiateAudit.setBatchID(batchId);
        initiateAudit.setSubscriptionID("1");
        initiateAudit.setFileName(fileName);
        
        System.out.println("Initiate audit");
        try {
            System.out.println("Creating audit obj");
            String env=System.getenv("AUDIT_BASE_URL");
            System.out.println("AUDIT_BASE_URL=="+env);
            AuditLibService auditLibService =new AuditLibService();
            
            log.debug(auditLibService);
            AuditResponse auditResponse1=null;
            System.out.println("Initiate audit req");
        auditResponse1=auditLibService.initiateAuditRequest("TEST",initiateAudit);
            log.debug(auditResponse1);
        System.out.println("response msg--"+auditResponse1.getRequestId()+"==="+auditResponse1.getRespMessage());
        
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        { 
            log.info("catch Audit-----");
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.debug("exception in initaitae audit-"+ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(e));
            }
        
        logging("Begin Writeback process" + tblName, "INFO", "Y");
        if(hiveTblName!=null && !hiveTblName.isEmpty())
        {
        
        wbc.writeBack(spark, batchId, br, fileName, logPath, oracleDbDetails,hiveTblName);
        
        
        }
        
        else
        {
        /*  completeAudit.setRequestId(auditResponse1.getRequestId());
            completeAudit.setStatus(WritebackAppConstants.FAILSTATUS);
            AuditResponse auditResponse2=auditLibService.completeAuditRequest("TEST2", completeAudit);*/
        }
    
        logging("End Writeback process", "INFO", "Y");
    }
    
}
```

Below code from project 2 :

```
public  AuditResponse initiateAuditRequest(String auditpoint , Object obj) {
        Map<String, String> reqMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        AuditResponse auditResponse =new AuditResponse();
        try {
            if(null!=auditpoint && null!=obj) {
                reqMap.put(auditpoint, new Gson().toJson(obj));
                if (null != System.getenv(AuditConstants.AUDIT_SERVICE_BASE_URL_ENV_VAR)) {
                    auditResponse = restTemplate.postForObject(endpoint_initiateauditrequest, reqMap, AuditResponse.class);
                } else {
                    auditResponse.setStatus(ApiStatusCodes.GEN_CON_API_ERR_CODE_ERROR);
                    auditResponse.setMessage("Environment variable "+AuditConstants.AUDIT_SERVICE_BASE_URL_ENV_VAR + " is NOT set in the project.Please setup and retry !");
                    LOG.error("Environment variable "+AuditConstants.AUDIT_SERVICE_BASE_URL_ENV_VAR + " is NOT set in the project.Please setup and retry !");
                }
            }else {
                auditResponse.setStatus(ApiStatusCodes.GEN_CON_API_ERR_CODE_ERROR);
                auditResponse.setMessage("Auditpoint or Object is null.Please correct and retry !");
                LOG.error("Auditpoint or Object is null.Please correct and retry !");
            }
            
        }  catch (Exception e) {
            auditResponse.setStatus(ApiStatusCodes.GEN_CON_API_ERR_CODE_ERROR);
            auditResponse.setMessage("Exception Occured while registring the request");
            LOG.error("Exception Occured while registring the request. Environment variable "+ System.getenv(AuditConstants.AUDIT_SERVICE_BASE_URL_ENV_VAR) ,e );
        }
        return auditResponse;
    }
}
```

please see below logs...

```
$ 0803083044.log /data/1/gfbcbn/bin/apps/etl/gen_snapshot/config/genesis_consumption_writeback_app.config                                                                                                     <
[main] INFO com.unraveldata.agent.ResourceCollector - Unravel Sensor 4.5.4.2b0003/1.3.11.3 initializing.
20/10/13 10:52:29 INFO security.HttpsClientInitializer: HTTP is enabled at the RPC server
20/10/13 10:52:29 INFO solution.WriteBackSolution: inside main..
Initiate audit
Creating audit obj
AUDIT_BASE_URL==http://sd-e3ca-fd19:8080
Initiate audit req
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate
        at com.citi.gfs.data.genesis.cons.audit.lib.services.AuditLibService.initiateAuditRequest(AuditLibService.java:270)
        at com.citi.gfs.data.genesis.cons.writeback.solution.WriteBackSolution.main(WriteBackSolution.java:207)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:851)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:926)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:935)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 14 more
```

Comment: Can you share full project1 file with import statements included?

Comment: Also add the error logs

Comment: @wak786 please see updated code & logs.

Comment: How are you referring to the project 2 inside project 1. Are you building the Jar of Project 2? If yes, try building jar with dependencies of project 2. I suspect project 2 does not contain dependencies.

Comment: @Ajinkya I have added the project 2 maven dependency in peoject 1

Comment: Yes that is not enough...Check the project 2 jar in the local maven repository. It must be the jar without dependencies. Build project 2 jar with dependencies. If project 2 is a springboot project then, build executable jar of project 2 as given in the example: https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven. Note that our purpose is to build the jar with dependencies, it is not neceassarily but executable jar but executable jar will also serve the purpose.

Comment: @Ajinkya When we are adding a external JAR, Build  is not successful, Getting error for AuditResponse which is present in Project 2.